# How to get composer local package dependencies to install?

Tags: composer-php

I have a global composer file for my user which contains references to local packages like:

```json
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "/vendorA/projectA",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "/vendorA/projectB",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "/vendorA/projectC",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In project C, I have a `composer.json` file similar to:

```json
{
    "name": "Project C"
    "require": {},
    "require-dev": {
        "vendorA/projectA": "@dev",
        "vendorA/projectB": "@dev"
    },
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

When I `composer require --dev vendorA/projectC`, it symlinks Project C's folder under the vendor folder but not the requirements defined in Project C's `composer.json` file. I tested installing Project A and B and they work fine so it is not a situation where composer is not able to find the packages, but Projects A and B don't install as well when project C is installed as a dependency of another project.

I also tried `"minimum-stability": "dev"` which did not work either.

Anyone know if I am missing something?

Comment: These dependencies are defined in `require-dev` of `vendorA/projectC`. Dev dependencies ale not installed if you install package as dependency - it will be installed only if `vendorA/projectC` is root project.

Comment: Interesting, I figured as long as you installed as dev it would still include the dev requirements. Know if there is any way to force it?

Comment: No. `require-dev` is for dependencies required for "development" this particular package, they're not installed if you only want to *use* it. Just require `vendorA/projectA` and `vendorA/projectB` directly if your project depends on them.